# Running bash function in command of su

Tags: bash, shell, su

In my bash script, I execute some commands as another user.  I want to call a bash function using `su`.

```
my_function()
{
  do_something
}

su username -c "my_function"
```

The above script doesn't work.  Of course, `my_function` is not defined inside `su`.  One idea I have is to put the function into a separate file.  Do you have a better idea that avoids making another file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can export the function to make it available to the subshell:

```
export -f my_function
su username -c "my_function"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could enable 'sudo' in your system, and use that instead.

Comment: sudo is not enabled. System admin won't enable it.

Comment: How do you do this with `sudo`? a simple `sudo my_function` will not work, even after exporting that function.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the function in the same scope where you use it. So either place the function inside the quotes, or put the function to a separate script, which you then run with su -c.

Comment: I'd like to call the same script outside su. The other script was my idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be making cases and passing a parameter to the executed script.
Example could be:
First make a file called "script.sh". 
Then insert this code in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

my_function() {
   echo "this is my function."
}

my_second_function() {
   echo "this is my second function."
}

case "$1" in
    'do_my_function')
        my_function
        ;;
    'do_my_second_function')
        my_second_function
        ;;
     *) #default execute
        my_function
esac
```

After adding the above code run these commands to see it in action:

```
root@shell:/# chmod +x script.sh  #This will make the file executable
root@shell:/# ./script.sh         #This will run the script without any parameters, triggering the default action.        
this is my function.
root@shell:/# ./script.sh do_my_second_function   #Executing the script with parameter
this function is my second one.
root@shell:/#
```

To make this work as you required you'll just need to run

```
su username -c '/path/to/script.sh do_my_second_function'
```

and everything should be working fine.
Hope this helps :)